# Running a function with manipulators in a popup window

Tags: manipulate, dialog-window

I have a function, pasted at the bottom, which I would like to encapsulate into a function that can be called, and the program would then run in a popup window, return the values energy, peaklocation and amplitude, then when the user is finished with the manipulate function, they'd press a done button and the popup window would close, returning the created data and the user to the workbook.

The issue is mainly that, while I can get a popup window to appear, I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to include manipulators. Is there any way to run the following as a function in a popup window, or am I better off simply getting it to save results to a file and running it manually?

Here's the code:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], PrintPrecision -> 10]
filelocation = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
rawfiledata = Import[filelocation, "Table"];
trimmedfiledata = Drop[rawfiledata, {1}, {2, 4}];
Manipulate[moveamt = movelength, {movelength, 1, 25, 1}]
DynamicWrapper["Select the left and right edges of the data", 
 mmdata = MovingAverage[trimmedfiledata, moveamt];]
minx = Min[mmdata[[All, 1]]];
minx = minx - 0.02;
maxx = Max[mmdata[[All, 1]]];
maxx = maxx + 0.02;
miny = Min[mmdata[[All, 2]]];
maxy = Max[mmdata[[All, 2]]];
Manipulate[leftEdge = left, {left, minx, maxx, 0.001}]
Manipulate[rightEdge = right, {{right, maxx}, minx, maxx, 0.001}]
Manipulate[c1 = peak, {peak, minx, maxx, 0.001}]
Manipulate[yoff = floor, {floor, miny, maxy, 0.001}]

(*d1 is edges*)
Dynamic[d1 = Select[mmdata, leftEdge < #[[1]] < rightEdge &];]

Dynamic[Show[
  ListPlot[mmdata, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   GridLines -> {{{c1, Orange}, leftEdge, rightEdge}, {{yoff, Red}}}],
  ParametricPlot[bsplinedat = BSplineFunction[mmdata][x], {x, -8, 8}],
  ListPlot[d1, PlotStyle -> Purple], ImageSize -> Large]]





Dynamic[f1 = 
  NonlinearModelFit[d1, a Exp[-(b (x - c1))^2] + yoff, {a, b}, x]]
Dynamic[Show[{ListPlot[d1], 
   Plot[f1[x], {x, d1[[1, 1]], d1[[-1, 1]]}, PlotRange -> All]}]]

Dynamic[Show[{ListPlot[mmdata], 
   Plot[f1[x], {x, minx, maxx}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]}]]

Dynamic[smooth2 = {#[[1]], #[[2]] - f1[#[[1]]]} & /@ mmdata;]
Dynamic[ListPlot[smooth2]]

Dynamic[energy = Integrate[Interpolation[mmdata][x], {x, minx, maxx}];]
Dynamic[peaklocation = c1;]
Dynamic[amplitude = f1[c1];]
b
Dynamic[s = 1/Sqrt[b]]
Dynamic[sd = StandardDeviation[d1]]
```

And here's some sample data, if needed for whatever reason:

http://www.pastebin.ca/3116443

Comment: I wonder if you could post a _simple_ example ...

Comment: Well, the simplest possible example would be Manipulate[moveamt = movelength, {movelength, 1, 25, 1}] just alone.

Comment: Im trying to apply any of the many popup schemes to it, from popup window to dialog, and preserve the manipulation within the created dialog, of whatever type.

Comment: ... Okay? Im not clear if you dont understand my question, or if you're just being obstinate. If you dont understand: Im trying to put a manipulate. ANY manipulate. Into a popup for a function. Just a general thing, can you put manipulates in popups, and if so, how. If you'd like, ignore the code sample and test data: Any manipulate. Any one. Into any popup. Is it possible?

Comment: One of these handy little dudes: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupWindow.html Or any of these https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DialogBoxes.html . My apologies if you are genuinely trying to help, "I wont" sempt to imply otherwise.

Comment: Please try to understand that many people come to these sites, dump their code and say "solve it for me".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: If the actual question is not what stated in the OP then it should be edited. As it is currently, its quite convoluted and hard to follow to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
f[aa_, oo_, pp_] := CreateDialog[
   Column[{Manipulate[
             Plot[(aa = amp) Sin[(oo = omega) t - (pp = phi)], {t, 0, 10}], 
             {amp, 0, 1}, {omega, 1, 10}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}], 
          DefaultButton["Close", DialogReturn[]]}], Modal -> True];
Dynamic[{a, o, p}]
f[Unevaluated@a, Unevaluated@o, Unevaluated@p]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Awesome. I misjudged you and was rude, and I apologize. This appears to work well, although the unevaluated  statements will take some tinkering to understand fully. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RNPF misjudging and loving at first sight are both equally dangerous. Have a nice day.