# How to create a new window with manipulate?

Tags: front-end, manipulate

How can I create a new window with a `Manipulate` expression?

Currently I'm using:

```
Manipulate[
  {ODE, ViewPD, IC},
  Column[{Row[{Style["ODE: ", Italic] }]}],
  {{ODE, x^2 + r, "x[t]="}, ControlType -> InputField},
  Grid[{{"Phase Diagram: "}}],
  {{ViewPD, False, "Show PD:"}, {True, False}, ControlType -> RadioButtonBar},
  {{IC, "{{r,x}}", "Initial Conditions:"}, InputField},     
  Grid[{{"Vector Field: "}}],
  {{ViewPD, False, "Show PD:"}, {True, False}, ControlType -> RadioButtonBar},
  {{IC, "{{r,x}}", "Initial Conditions:"}, InputField},
  Grid[{{"Poincare Sections: "}}],
  {{ViewPD, False, "Show PD:"}, {True, False}, ControlType -> RadioButtonBar},
  {{IC, "{{r,x}}", "Initial Conditions:"}, InputField}, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

The result is displayed in the notebook containing the `Manipulate` expression. Now I need the result to be displayed in a new window.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. It would be good if you could format your post for better readability. Help on this can be found on the top right corner of the edit box.

Comment: I use Guess Who It Is' answer here a lot. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92470/creating-detached-plots/92498#92498
Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I write manipulate functions I: execute the code,delete everything but the running manipulate window, and then save as a computable document (.cdf). Then whenever I open it it's just the manipulate window.

I personally don't mind the extra white space, but if you do maybe check out belisarius's post in [Running a function with manipulators in a popup window](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91959/running-a-function-with-manipulators-in-a-popup-window), it appears to do what you're looking for.

**Edit:** Here's an example of what it looks like.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, yes it what he wanted.